# Object literal in JavaScript try block

Tags: javascript

```
try{
 {a:1}
}
catch(e){}
```

```
try{
 a:1
}
catch(e){}
```

The outputs of above blocks are '1' in chrome console. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those two code blocks contains an object literal.

In both cases `a:1` is interpreted as a label `a` followed by a statement that's just `1`.

The [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `a` doesn't do anything unless it's used in a `break` or `continue` statement.

Similarly `1` as a statement also doesn't do anything other than return its value (which is why the whole expression will evaluate to `1` and thus print that value, when executed from the developer console).

In the first case the extra pair of `{}` is just a local code block. In other words, it would usually be layed out like this:

```
try {
  {
    a:1
  }
}
catch(e) {}
```

To make the `{a:1}` actually be interpreted as an object literal you need to wrap it in parenthesis:

```
try {
 ({a:1})
}
catch(e) {}
```

I honestly don't quite know why you would *want* that, but executing this code block in your console will print the object, as you expected.

Comment: What's the meaning of 'a:1'?

Comment: I already explained how it's interpreted and I've expanded the explanation above to hopefully be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The JS parser doesn't see an object literal in the examples, but a label and a number literal.

In the first example, the parser sees:

```
try {
  {
    a: 1;
  }
} catch (e) {}
```

So there's a block inside the `try` block, and inside that block there's a [**label**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) `a` and a single expression statement with a number literal expression `1`.

The second example is the same, but without the additional block.

Chrome's console outputs the results of an evaluation in the console, in this case the number literal `1`, which is why you see the number `1` in the console.

Comment: Why chrome evaluate 'a:1' to 1?

Comment: @leili The `a:` here is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). The kinds you see with `goto` in other languages. So if you remove the `a:` from there, it's just `1` which ultimately gives you the same output as if you'd just enter `1` in the console.